# Platform settings not showing up on IntelliJ Idea 14 under Preference

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am using IntelliJ Idea and want to configure java. Hence when I hit the command , I get the Preference settings. However, I am not seeing the Platform Settings under the Preference section. Please let me know where I am going wrong. I am using IntelliJ Idea 14 on my Mac 10.9.5 OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to configure?
The SDK preferences are under Project Structure in Platform Settings, there you can add new SDKs, if you want to select the SDK that your project will use you need to select it in Project under Project Settings on the same window.